# Show UILocalNotification as alert

Tags: ios, alert, uilocalnotification

Here in the iOS app I need to show the notificatio as alert when it fired (Not as the banner appeard on the top of screen). Can you please suggets me the way to do so.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: You can show local notification in alertView when the app is in foreground, not in background/suspended mode.

Comment: How the notification is show when you app is not running in under the control of the user. They can select the styl in the setting of you app.

Comment: If your question is can you programmatically change the style of a notification then the answer is no. Its not clear what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications will not be displayed as an alert in the app if the app is active when the notification is received.
You can implement the following method in the `AppDelegate.m`, which is called when the app receives a local notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{
     NSString *alertTitle = notification.title;
     NSString *alertBody = notification.alertBody;

     // Show alert here

}
```

When the user then opens the app, an alert will be shown.

Comment: Here what you want to show? Please read the question carefully.

Actually when we ask user for the permissions regarding notification, and if users accept the proposal then when the notification fired there is a small alert on the top of screen when app is in background right?

But I need this as alert in the centre of screen as UIAlert when app is active.

Thank

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I have updated the answer with a solution